# Enable text search on more than first 34 SEDE query results

Tags: bug, user-interface, data-explorer

I was recently running [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361199?tag=url-encoding) to determine which Stack Overflow users could vote for tag synonyms suggestions based on the target tag of that suggestion (in my case, as linked above, I was looking at [url-encoding](/questions/tagged/url-encoding)). For fun, I decided to check if Jon Skeet was able to vote on [url-encoding](/questions/tagged/url-encoding) suggestions (aka whether he has answer score of at least 5 in the tag). I typed <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, searched for "skeet", and found that the name didn't show up. Later, when scrolling through the list of results, I happened to notice his name (the 42nd one on the list). On the three browsers I've tested on (Google Chrome 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit), Mozilla Firefox 40.0.3, and Safari 7.1.8), only the first 34 results are searchable after the query loads; more are searchable as you scroll down in Chrome and Firefox but I often had trouble searching even after scrolling on Safari.

Personally, I think it's important to be able to search through the results of a SEDE query. Drawing a few examples from the [most popular Stack Overflow SEDE queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular):

- [How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) -- users might want to search for a particular tag that's far down on the list.
- [Most controversial posts on the site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) -- users might want to search (by title) if a particular post made the list.
- [High Standards - Top 100 Users that rarely upvote](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote) -- users might want to search if a particular user is on the "high standards" list.

I would imagine that the motivation for not making all results searchable is that it may slow down page load times for queries that return a huge number of results (queries can return up to 50,000 results). However, users are already waiting for the query to finish, so a bit of extra time on the page load probably isn't a big deal. I think most users would expect query results to be fully searchable if their query returned a few hundred rows, so I would like to request that the number of searchable results be increased from 34 to at least a few hundred (and ideally fully searchable).

Comment: It is not even that the data is not yet available in the browser, they didn't get yet added to the dom. So you technically have all the data available to find what you're looking for. But I have browsed over some of the SEDE code and I can't find an extension point where I can hookup a userscript to fix this temporarily. With that said, I wonder if it is a bug as such. The grid isn't searchable and their is no code yet to make that happen. And it doesn't seem to be default available on SlickGrid so I guess we need to bake something special.