# Demographic of users on different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in the demographic of users on non-CS-related SE sites (think Travel, Cooking, etc.).

Specifically, I'm interested in knowing how many of them are programmers.
I imagine a not-so-terrible way to measure that is to see how many of them are on SO.

Have these ever been investigated anywhere? How can I find them out?

---

#### Update:

Just like I suspected, on almost all SE sites, most people seem to be programmers.

Perhaps it's just me, but this seems like an astonishingly biased demographic for sites like Cooking, English, Travel, etc., which have nothing to do with programming.

@Admins/Mods/Powers-that-be:  Have you considered whether this is desirable?

Comment: Not sure, but the only way to do it IMHO is to see how many users also have an account in a programming-related site.  Not a fool-proof method, but is good enough though!

Comment: @Dawny33: Whoops, that was a typo on my end. I meant to say the same thing as you but accidentally copied the sentence above! Fixed.

Comment: How can you know who is programmer and who is not? Sounds like it requires a manual survey of some sort?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: 3rd line?

Comment: So you mean users that have accounts both in SO and other sites?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes.

Comment: "Has an account on SO" probably isn't a meaningful benchmark.  People can have those accounts for various reasons -- member of a team (which only works through SO), maintains a career page there (so probably *technical* but not necessarily a *programmer*), clicked a link and signed up once five years ago... Even if someone has rep, 500 rep on SO vs 50k rep on Cooking tells me that programming probably isn't this person's *focus*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're for the simplest case only interested interested in the number of users on a site that also have an Stack Overflow account, the following [multi-database query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/475533) gives you those numbers:

```sql
  -- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)

      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                         and ([name] not like '%.meta' or [Name] = 'Meta.StackExchange')
                         and [Name] <> 'Stackoverflow'

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_users ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , total bigint
                            , totso bigint);

open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_users 
               select @url
               , count(*)
               , sum(case when s.id is not null 
                          then 1 
                          else 0
                     end)
               from users u 
               left outer join Stackoverflow.dbo.users s 
                            on s.accountid = u.accountid;'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , total as [All Users]
     , totso as [Users also on SO]
     , cast(totso as float) / total * 100 as [%]
from #all_users
order by cast(totso as float) / total * 100 desc

drop table #all_users

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

When run today the first rows look like this:

[image: users that also have an SO account]

If you consider users to be participating on a site only after they reached 200 reputation [this fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/475575/demographic-of-200-rep-users-on-different-stack-exchange-sites) might be interesting, thanks to [Marshmellow](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4831753#4831753).

Comment: Wow, **4%** of Code Golf users don't have an SO account. That means they join SE *just* to play Code Golf. That's pretty cool :P

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton! Question: why are some sites not on that list? (e.g. English.SE)

Comment: @Mehrdad in the live query I see English way down the list, and English Language and Learners is a bit cryptic because that site is indicated as `ell`, so you need a bit of fantasy to link to the correct site.

Comment: @rene: Huh, it shows up now, for some reason I couldn't find it last time I looked. Thanks! (Edit: Ah, the browser search functionality doesn't always work here if it's out of the scroll window...)

Comment: @Mehrdad yeah, that slickgrid component does load the items dynamically in the DOM so you first need to scroll all the way down before a search will find what you expect to find. You might want to support this bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266093/enable-text-search-on-more-than-first-34-sede-query-results

Comment: Scrolled all the way to the bottom to discover Hermeneutics has the second lowest proportion (29%) - that's pretty good for a non-CS academic discipline, and does sound about right for our community. Thanks for sharing!